# Matar aplicativo sem root

Tags: android

Existe alguma maneira de matar uma outra aplicação (que não a minha) via código sem usar um comando root pra isso?
Estou tentando usar o comando "am force-stop ", mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Você quer apenas fechar a aplicação ou destruí-la?

Comment: não quero matar a minha aplicação, quero matar outras que estão sendo executadas.

Answer (score 0):

Você só consegue se comunicar com outra aplicação se ela deixar.
Exemplo: se você quer fechar o YouTube, o YouTube precisa deixar você fazer isso.

Eu não sei ao certo qual é o comando mas eu recomendo que você leia isto aqui: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Comment: eu consigo sim matar outra aplicação através de comandos root como "kill -9 pid", só que pra isso preciso de acesso root. Eu queria uma alternativa pra isso, e não enviar uma mensagem ao outro aplicativo

Comment: @LuizHenriqueAlegria Nunca pesquisei, mas provavelmente não é possível sem root.

Comment: @ErickFilho possível deve ser, visto que tem apps que matam aplicações sem precisar de root. Battery Doctor é um exemplo.

Comment: @LuizHenriqueAlegria Verdade, dá uma olhada aqui: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String) será que te ajuda? Tenta passar o pakageName do YouTube.

Comment: @ErickFilho quase consegui com o ActivityManager, mas ainda não deu certo. Esse método apenas mata aplicações relacionadas a minha aplicação.

Answer (score -1):

**Você pode usar para destruir:**

*finish();*

Use esse método para "matar" a aplicação sem root.

Comment: acredito que não fui muito claro em minha questão. Eu desejo matar outra aplicação e não a minha própria.

Comment: Então é só implementar o método onDestroy.

Comment: onDestroy? como eu poderia por exemplo matar a aplicação do youtube apenas com esse método?

Answer (score -1):

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Comment: Poderia explicar sua resposta?